# Windows cannot be installed to this disk. Ensure the disk's

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, installation, motherboard

I recently put together a self built rig. The all the parts seem to work, but when I try to install windows 8, I get the following error message:

```
'Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.'
```

All the parts are brand new and the hdd isn't partitioned or formatted (Windows says that its 'unallocated space'). The only options I have in this screen are 'refresh', 'load drivers', and 'new'. I have already installed the drivers included with my motherboard, and that didn't help. I have also tried to create a partition in cmd using DISKPART, and I get a "cyclic redundancy check" error.

Here are my specs:

- AMD FX 6350
- ASUS M5A99FX PRO
- R9 280X
- Western Digital Blue 1 TB HDD
- Asus optical drive

EDIT: Today my friend came over with an Xubuntu disk aswell as an Ubuntu disk. Neither of them could be installed. We now think it may be a hard drive issue now. Does this sound like a HDD that's DOA?

Comment: Have you connected the HDD to one of the lower SATA connectors (SATA6G_1 to SATA6G_4 according to [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A99FX_PRO_R20/E8043_M5A99FX_PRO_R2.pdf))?

Comment: Click "New" to partition the disk - use the entire disk space.

Comment: You should also be able to click the "unallocated space" which should enable the "next button"... a blank disk should prompt setup to say that a small partition will be created for startup files.

Comment: Is there a jumper on the hard drive to set it as slave/master? What about on your optical drive?

Comment: @Andrew it wasn't in the ports you specified, i'll try that.

Comment: SATA drives don't come with slave/master jumpers.